# Why can't get matrix what I passed to Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, matrix

I want to do some basic stuff: get a matrix, and iterate on it with multiple threads. For example, if I have a 20x20 sized matrix, and I have 4 threads, then the first Thread have to iterate on the 5x20 sized matrix, the second one has to iterate on the same size, but from the 6th row to the 10th one, and so on. But, my program gets only the first part, the second, and third, fourth threads can't see their submatrixes. Why? Can anyone help me with this?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace multi_thred_test
{
    class thredData 
    {
        public int my_simulation_size;
        public int[,] my_simulation;
        public string my_path;
        public int my_nrOfAvailableThreads;
        public int my_oneThreeadSubsimulationSize;

        public thredData(ref int simsize, ref int[,] simu, ref string path, ref int availabelthrd, ref int subsimsize )
        {
            my_simulation_size = simsize;
            my_simulation = new int[simsize, simsize];
            for (int i = 0; i < simsize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < simsize; j++)
                {
                    my_simulation[i, j] = simu[i, j];
                }
            }
            my_path = path;
            my_nrOfAvailableThreads = availabelthrd;
            my_oneThreeadSubsimulationSize = subsimsize;
        }

    }
    
    class Program
    {
        public static int simulation_size = 20;
        public static int[,] simulation = new int[20, 20];
        public static string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        public static int nrOfAvailableThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        public static int oneThreeadSubsimulationSize = simulation_size / nrOfAvailableThreads;
        public static thredData tmp;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int idx = 0; idx < simulation_size; idx++)
            {
                for (int jdx = 0; jdx < simulation_size; jdx++)
                {
                    simulation[idx, jdx] = idx * 100 + jdx;
                }
            }
            
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + "_matrix.txt");
            for (int idx = 0; idx < simulation_size; idx++)
            {
                for (int jdx = 0; jdx < simulation_size; jdx++)
                {
                    sw.Write(simulation[idx, jdx]+" ");
                }
                sw.WriteLine(" ");
            }
            sw.Close();

            tmp = new thredData(ref simulation_size, ref simulation, ref path, ref nrOfAvailableThreads, ref oneThreeadSubsimulationSize);

            //generate threads
            for (int thrdnr = 0; thrdnr < nrOfAvailableThreads; thrdnr++)
            {
                Thread newThread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
                newThread.Name = Convert.ToString(thrdnr);
                newThread.Start();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void ThreadMethod()
        {
            Thread thr = Thread.CurrentThread;
            int simulationSize = Convert.ToInt32(thr.Name);

            int thrd_simulation_size;
            int[,] thrd_simulation;
            string thrd_path;
            int thrd_nrOfAvailableThreads;
            int thrd_oneThreeadSubsimulationSize;

            lock (tmp)
            {
                thrd_simulation_size = tmp.my_simulation_size;
                thrd_simulation = new int[thrd_simulation_size, thrd_simulation_size];

                for (int i = 0; i < tmp.my_simulation_size; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < tmp.my_simulation_size; j++)
                    {
                        thrd_simulation[i, j] = tmp.my_simulation[i, j];
                    }
                }
                thrd_path = tmp.my_path;
                thrd_nrOfAvailableThreads = tmp.my_nrOfAvailableThreads;
                thrd_oneThreeadSubsimulationSize = tmp.my_oneThreeadSubsimulationSize;
            }

            for (int i = thrd_simulation_size * simulationSize; i < thrd_oneThreeadSubsimulationSize; i++)
             {
             for (int j = 0; j < thrd_simulation_size; j++)
             {
                 Console.Write(thr.Name +":"+ thrd_simulation[i,j] + " ");
             }
            Console.Write("\n");
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use Thread class, use Tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the log part was wrong:

```
            for (int i = thrd_oneThreeadSubsimulationSize * simulationSize; i < (thrd_oneThreeadSubsimulationSize * simulationSize) +thrd_oneThreeadSubsimulationSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < thrd_simulation_size; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(thr.Name + ":" + thrd_simulation[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
```